# jQuery Plugin - slider.unslider is not a Function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a lot of trouble attempting to use a slider style jQuery plugin with Ajax. I am attempting to create a pop-up with a slideshow in it. However, initially, it simply would not work. The images just displayed in list format as if I were not using the plugin at all. So, I attempted to use one of the plugins methods for testing. Now I receive the error: slider.unslider is not a function. Why might this be?

`base.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sandwichMenu").hide();
    $(".videoContainer").hide();
    $("#sliderBody").hide();
    $("#reminderContent").hide();

    timerVar = setTimeout(getSlideshow, 1000 * 60 );
    checkTime = setInterval(checkReminder, 1000 * 60);
    var slider = $("#slider").unslider({ autoplay: true, nav: false, arrows: false });

    slider.on('unslider.ready', function() {
        alert('Slider is set up!');
    });

    document.onmousemove = function() { clearTimeout(timerVar); timerVar = setTimeout(getSlideshow, 1000 * 60 ); }
    document.onkeypress = function() { clearTimeout(timerVar); timerVar = setTimeout(getSlideshow, 1000 * 60 ); }
    document.onclick = function() { clearTimeout(timerVar); timerVar = setTimeout(getSlideshow, 1000 * 60 ); }

    $('#thumbGallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image'
    });

    $('.vidButton').click(function() {
        $(".vidButton").removeClass('active');
        $(".videoContainer").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $("#sandwichButton").click(function() {
        $("#sandwichMenu").toggle();
    });

    $("#sliderBody").click(function() {
        $("#sliderBody").hide();
    });

    $("#reminderContent").click(function() {
        $("#reminderContent").hide();
    });
});

function getSlideshow() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/slideshow.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#slider").html(data);
            slider.unslider("start");
            $("#sliderBody").show();
        }
    });

    clearTimeout(timerVar); timerVar = setTimeout(getSlideshow, 1000 * 60 );
}

function checkReminder() {
    $.ajax( { 
        url: "php/checkReminder.php",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data != "false") {
                $("#reminderContent").html(data);
                $("#reminderContent").show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`slideshow.php` (referred to by the relevant Ajax function)

```
<?php

include_once("databaseAccess.php");
include_once("dbEntities.php");
$dbContext = new databaseAccess();

// get number of messages
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

$images = $dbContext->getScreenSaver();
$htmlString = "<ul>";

foreach($images as $image) {
    $htmlString .= "<li><img class='img-responsive' src='img/screensaver/" . $image->imgPath . "' /></li>";
}

$htmlString .= "</ul>";
echo $htmlString;
exit();
```

`footer.php` (includes the relevant scripts)

```
<footer> <div class="row"><div class='col-md-12'>
Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
Midamerica Hotels Corporation || All Rights Reserved </div></div></footer> </div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/unslider.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/base.js"></script>
<script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: your `slider` variable is defined within your `$(document).ready` function, so only exists within that context. But the place you're referencing it (the `getSlideshow()` function is outside that context, so it doesn't know what "slider" is. Either move `getSlideShow()` (and anything which references it) within the document.ready context, or declare "slider" as a global outside that context.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I made var slider a global variable, and, while I am no longer receiving an error, I am also not receiving any response. That is, I am not getting the alert "Slider is set up" nor is my slider actually sliding. It just displays a list of images. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: would be helpful if you edit your code, or post a JSFiddle with the latest version so we can see exactly where the problem might be